# Setting \crefname dynamically

Tags: macros, cleveref

My goal:

```
\begin{equation}[singular=<sing_flag>,plural=<plur_flag>]\label{eq:1}
    a < b
\end{equation}
\cref{eq:1}
```

yields `<sing_flag> (1)` for *any input* for `singular` and `plural` (I'd like to avoid specifying a `\crefname` for every equation type manually).

Basic Idea: When `singular` and/or `plural` are passed create new counter (within equation) as anker for `cleveref` and pass `singular`/`plural` to `\crefname`.

### Problems:

- Just setting `\crefname` doesn't work, for some reason I have to set `\crefformat` etc, which is cumbersome and doesn't automate well with babel
- Even `\crefformat` doesn't quite work. It just uses the default settings for `singular` and `plural`.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%% Packages
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter

%% New Counter for counting new types of equations
\newcounter{misitex@formulatypes}

%% Set up for options
\define@cmdkey[misitex]{equation}{singular}{}
\define@cmdkey[misitex]{equation}{plural}{}
\setkeys[misitex]{equation}{singular=none,plural=none} % initialize

%% Save old equation env
\let\oldequation\equation
\let\endoldequation\endequation

%% Set Crefformat
\newcommand{\misitex@setcrefformat}[3]{
    SetCrefFormat gets: \noexpand{#2} \noexpand{#3}

    %% Shouldn't this suffice?
    \crefname{#1}{#2}{#3}
    \Crefname{#1}{#2}{#3}

    %% Why do I need this?
    \crefformat{#1}{##2#2~\upshape{(##1)}##3}
    \crefrangeformat{#1}{
        ##3#3~\upshape{(##1)}##4 to~##5\upshape{(##2)}##6
    }
    \crefmultiformat{#1}{##2#3~\upshape{(##1)}##3}%
        { and~##2\upshape{(##1)}##3}%
        {, ##2\upshape{(##1)})}%
        { and~##2\upshape{(##1)}##3}
}

%% Set options only if passed
\NewDocumentCommand{\misitex@equation@parse}{m m}{
    \IfValueTF{#1}{\setkeys[misitex]{equation}{#1}}{}
    \IfValueTF{#2}{\setkeys[misitex]{equation}{#2}}{}
}

%% Create new type of equation
\newcommand{\misitex@eqaution@setnew}[2]{
    % Add new equation counter
    \stepcounter{misitex@formulatypes}
    \newaliascnt{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{equation}

    % Set cref format
    \misitex@setcrefformat{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{#1}{#2}

    % Refstep for cref
    \refstepcounter{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}

    % Set Equation Numbering
    \def\eqNumber{\eqno{\hbox{\upshape{
                    (\csname themisitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes \endcsname)
        }}}\@ignoretrue}
}

%% Renew Equation env
%% If singular/plural is passed: cerate new counter and apply cref names
%% Else just use old equation env
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}o}{
    % Parse Arguments
    \IfValueT{#1}{\misitex@equation@parse #1}%

    \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdmisitex@equation@singular}{none}}%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdmisitex@equation@plural}{none}}%
            {%
                \oldequation%
            }{%
                \misitex@eqaution@setnew%
                    {\cref@equation@name}{\cmdmisitex@equation@plural}%
                $$
            }%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdmisitex@equation@plural}{none}}%
            {%
                \misitex@eqaution@setnew%
                    {\cmdmisitex@equation@singular}{\cref@equation@name@plural}%
                $$%
            }{%
                \misitex@eqaution@setnew%
                    {\cmdmisitex@equation@singular}
                    {\cmdmisitex@equation@plural}%
                $$%
            }%
    }%
}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdmisitex@equation@singular}{none}}%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdmisitex@equation@plural}{none}}%
            {
                \endoldequation
            }%
            {\eqNumber $$}%
    }{
        \eqNumber $$
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}[singular=Ineq.,plural=Ineqs.]\label{test}
     a = b
    \end{equation}

    \cref{test}

    \begin{equation}\label{test2}
    a = b
    \end{equation}

    \cref{test,test2}
\end{document}
```

#### Outputs:

[image]

So while it seems that `singular` and `plural` are passed to `\crefformat` correctly, `\cref` uses the default `none`.

---

While I'm aware, that this is quite a specific problem, I'm glad for any advise :)

Comment: The user guide of the `cleveref` package has a section about dynamic renaming of item types, say, to create a different call-out for inequalities. Did you give that method a try?

Comment: I'm not quite shure, which section you mean. Can you give a number? [`cleveref`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)

Comment: Section 6, "Overriding the Cross-Reference Type".

Comment: Mh, that's actually what I'm doing/want to do in `\misitex@setcrefformat`. In your linked question, only _one_ other equation type is needed. However, I want to be able to set `singular` and `plural` dynamically without adding a `\crefname` to the preamble each time.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your 'without adding a \crefname to the preamble each time' concern. Your draft code contains 101[!] lines; the added, ineq-related instructions occupy all of 3 lines.

Comment: I'm aware that my intend goes against most "best practice" advises. Consider it a proof of concept if you will.

Comment: You wrote, "I'd like to avoid specifying a `\crefname` for every equation type manually". The likely serious downside of the approach you've outlined is that, in order to make is usable for environments *other* than `equation`, you'll need to provide code for `align`, `gather`, `multline`, `alignat`, etc etc environments a well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that `\crefname` doesn't define global commands. A workaround is to use the capability of `cleveref` to read a file `cleveref.cfg` befor compilation. By writing the `\crefname` directives to that file, the desired solution is achieved.

### MWE:

Note that the command hanling has been altered, which however is not the actual point of the question.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{misitex@formulatypes}

\let\oldequation\equation
\let\endoldequation\endequation

%% Open file
\newwrite\cleverefcfg
\immediate\openout\cleverefcfg=cleveref.cfg

%% Some shortcuts to write special characters to file
\begingroup\lccode`?=`# \lowercase{\endgroup
    \newcommand{\hashsymb}{?}
}
\begingroup\lccode`?=`{ \lowercase{\endgroup
    \newcommand{\bracksymbo}{?}
}
\begingroup\lccode`?=`} \lowercase{\endgroup
    \newcommand{\bracksymbc}{?}
}
\begingroup\lccode`?=`\% \lowercase{\endgroup
    \newcommand{\commentsymb}{?}
}

%% write cleveref directives to file
\newcommand{\creflabelformat@tofile}[1]{
    \if@cref@nameinlink
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            \string\creflabelformat{#1}\bracksymbo\hashsymb\commentsymb%
        }
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            2\string\textup\bracksymbo(\hashsymb\commentsymb
        }
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            1)\bracksymbc\hashsymb\commentsymb
        }
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            3\bracksymbc\commentsymb
        }
    \else
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            \string\creflabelformat{#1}\bracksymbo\string\textup\bracksymbo(\hashsymb\commentsymb%
        }
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            2\hashsymb\commentsymb
        }
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            1\hashsymb\commentsymb
        }
        \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
            3)\bracksymbc\bracksymbc\commentsymb
        }
    \fi
}

%% Renew equation env
%% Input may be [<cstm number>], [<sing>][<plur>], or [<cstm number>][<sing>][<plur>]
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{o o o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            \oldequation
            \IfValueT{#1}{\tag{#1}}
        }{
            \IfValueT{#1}{
                \stepcounter{misitex@formulatypes}
                \newaliascnt{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{equation}
                
                %% Write \crefname instruction to config file
                \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
                    \string\crefname{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{#1}{#2}
                    \string\Crefname{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{#1}{#2}
                }
                \creflabelformat@tofile{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}
            }
            \oldequation
            \IfValueT{#1}{
                \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
                \refstepcounter{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}
            }
        }
    }{
        \IfValueT{#2}{
            \stepcounter{misitex@formulatypes}
            \newaliascnt{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{equation}
    
            %% Write \crefname instruction to config file
            \protected@write\cleverefcfg{}{
                \string\crefname{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{#2}{#3}
                \string\Crefname{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}{#2}{#3}
            }
            \creflabelformat@tofile{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}
        }
        \oldequation
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{
            \IfValueT{#2}{
                \expandafter\def\csname themisitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes\endcsname{#1}
                \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
            }
            \renewcommand{\theequation}{#1}
        }
        \IfValueT{#2}{
            \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
            \refstepcounter{misitex@formulatype@\themisitex@formulatypes}
        }
    }
}{
    \endoldequation
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}[a]\label{test}
     a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}[Ineq][Ineqs]\label{test2}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}[c]\label{test3}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}[Formula][Formulae]\label{test4}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}[Formula][Formulae]\label{test45}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}\label{test5}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    
    \cref{test,test2,test3,test4,test5,test45}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

### Note

As shown, equations `(2)` and `(3)` are not grouped as `Formulae (2) and (3)`. This however is a general problem an can be reproduced in a much simpler setting. A workaround is to explicitly set `\crefformat` in addition to `\crefname`.